# AJAX CSRF attacks and .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xss, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-mvc-ajax

This post describes a tokening system for all JSON HttpGet and HttpPost AJAX calls:

In short, you use the AntiForgeryToken attribute to create a token on the page, and then manually validate that that value is sent back to the controller via the AJAX call.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

After hours of internet sleuthing, there are always references to this possibility, but no one actually implements it.  Instead the commonly repeated techniques are 1) using only HttpPost AJAX requests (which breaks REST), 2) wrapping all json responses in an anonymous object, which results in significantly inelegant code in .net MVC4, 3) using an unparsable cruf, which breaks common libraries such as backbone.js

**So why aren't we all using the tokening system linked above?  What am I missing?**

Comment: What makes you think "no one actually implements it"?  I certainly do, and others I know do.  I think you have a false premise.  Also, your link doesn't work.  Also, this is not about generic XSS, this is specifically about CSRF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about CSRF, and your concerned about REST and doing REST correctly, then you shouldn't be doing anything in a GET that would be affected by a CSRF, since the entire purpose of AntiForgeryTokens is to deal with changing data (ie, you can't use an AntiForgeryToken without first getting the page anyways that contains the token).

So, saying using POST "breaks REST" seems to be misunderstanding what you're using the token for in the first place.  It's true that a GET can expose sensitive information, but you have to have some way to get the token first if you want to use it with GET.

The real problem with Ajax and AntiForgeryToken with json and Ajax is that the "built-in" validation only works with form values, not json.  So you have to do the validation yourself, and that article you linked to gives a good explanation of how to do that.

Comment: Let's say that I have a webpage that displays a user's financial data in an interactive manner.  From my perspective, the process would be: 

1) the user logs into a page that has been validated w/ antiforgery and authenticate attributes


2) A JS script collects user preferences, and submits an HttpGet to get the data.  The JS then builds the page.


Now we have a public action, that responds via Json, via a Get, that can be affected by an XSS attack.  Using a POST in this scenerio would break REST, no?  And using the method in the link would solve the problem, correct?

Comment: @RobertChrist - you can't really "log into a page that has been validated by the antiforgery token", because you cannot pass a token on a get from the brower (when you type the url into the address bar, or click on a link that does not execute as ajax), unless you did it on the URL and that would be unwise.  Even so, you need to somehow get the token first to be able to validate it on the server.

Comment: @RobertChrist - Yes, you could use the method linked in an Ajax get method, but you can't do it on the page itself, only on the content you get from the ajax request.